# How to repair small tears in leather couch

Tags: repair, furniture, hole-repair, upholstery

I have a leather couch that is only 3+ years old and has now started to develop small tears around the seams in one of the cushions. Here is an image of the tears:
[image]

I think it would be best to try and fix the issue now to prevent the tears for worsening but given their small sizes, it seems that it might be hard to do something like a patch. I've seen kits like [this one](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B08375KJKD) on Amazon which seem to be appropriate for this situation. Would using this kind of leather repair kit be the best option to handle this case or is there a more suitable alternative.

Comment: sawing back together

Comment: hot glue a strip of scrap denim from behind, using an iron to smooth it out and really fuse the materials.

Comment: Those kits might work in experienced hands. As a one-off DIY you will make a complete mess of it. If, as you say in comments you cannot get to the back of it, then it's time to call a professional. If the leather is that weak [split leather, painted finish is the worst], then you might want to get them to do the same to all the stress seams before they do the same thing. Leather repair work is *expensive*. If the sofa was cheap, you might be better off looking for a new one.

Comment: Darn you English and your homonyms! As I was reading this, I was thinking "those tares would elicit tears, but that's spelled wrong!". No, no it's not spelled wrong...

Answer (score 1):

Reinforce from behind - a sticky tape or patch.

**Don't** make more holes for sewing...

Comment: I can't unzip the cushion to be able to place anything behind the tears.

Comment: Two now suggext repairing from behind - work through the hole...